# Share an internet connection within three separate subnetworks/VLANs

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, subnet, dhcp

I want to share a FO/Internet connection among three separate small offices.

Internet provider modem/router has LAN 192.168.1.0/24, with its gateway at 192.168.1.1 and serving IPs (192.168.1.100-200) via DHCP to all its LAN PORTS.

|CPE INTERNET PROVIDER|----- 192.168.1.1

I would like to serve the following separate subnetworks:

NETWORK 2
ETH ----- 192.168.2.0/24 (DHCP RANGE 192.168.2.100-192.168.2.200)

NETWORK 3
ETH ----- 192.168.3.0/24 (DHCP RANGE 192.168.3.100-192.168.3.200)

NETWORK 4
ETH ----- 192.168.4.0/24 (DHCP RANGE 192.168.4.100-192.168.4.200)

I am thinking in the following setup, with either a Ubiquity EdgeRouter or a SMB Cisco:

```
 __________________________________________
|         CPE INTERNET PROVIDER            |
|               192.168.1.1                |
|                   /16                    |    
|__________________________________________|
                     .
                     .
                     .
 __________________________________________
|               192.168.1.2                |
|                   /16                    |
|                WAN PORT1                 |
|                                          |
|               CISCO OR UBIQUITI          |
|                                          |
| LAN PORT2      LAN PORT3     LAN PORT4   |
| 192.168.2.1    192.168.3.1   192.168.4.1 |
|     /24            /24           /24     |
|   (VLAN2)        (VLAN3)       (VLAN4)   |
|__________________________________________|
     .               .              .
     .               .              .
     .               .              .
     .               .              .
SUBNETWORK2     SUBNETWORK3    SUBNETWORK4
```

1. configuring the Internet CPE modem/router LAN to 192.168.1.0/16.
2. disable DHCP in that CPE.
3. attach a Cisco SMB RV325 or a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter, with:

   a) its WAN interface configured to 192.168.1.2/16
   b) VLAN2 configured in LAN Port 2 with network 192.168.2.0/24
   c) VLAN3 configured in LAN Port 3 with network 192.168.3.0/24
   d) VLAN4 configured in LAN Port 4 with network 192.168.4.0/24
   e) DHCP Pool configured in LAN Port 2 with IP Range 192.168.2.100-192.168.2.200
   f) DHCP Pool configured in LAN Port 3 with IP Range 192.168.3.100-192.168.3.200
   g) DHCP Pool configured in LAN Port 4 with IP Range 192.168.4.100-192.168.4.200

LAN ETH ports 2,3,4 would serve via ethernet cables the small offices, where a regular switch at the ends would allow connect all devices.

My doubts are:

1. does this setup make sense?
2. Do CISCO SMB RV325 or Ubiquiti EdgePro allow to configure separate DHCP pools per VLAN/PORT?
3. How do I ensure that VLANs/subnetworks are not reachable between them?

Thanks,

Comment: Your setup looks good to me.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

1 - the setup make sense, but there's one potential issue:
The ISP provided CPE may not NAT networks others than 192.168.1.0/24 to the Public IP address. I.E. it will not perform NAT for the 3 subnetworks. If this is the case, you may have to NAT those 3 networks with IP from the 192.168.1.0/24 network.

(btw there's a discrepancy between the text `Internet provider modem/router has LAN 192.168.1.0/24` and the schema where it is noted as `/16`, I assume the correct one is /24 as it is the most common case)

2 - For DHCP

- Cisco SMB RV325
  It is not clear from [this user manual](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv320/administration/guide/en/rv32x_ag_en.pdf) that you can configure separate DHCP pools, but there's 90% chance it is the case.

  In the [CLI reference guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv320/CLI_guide/rv32x_cli_guide.pdf) it is not explicit either but the syntax use seems to imply it is possible.

> interface vlan modify 25 dhcp 192.168.22.2~192.168.22.150 dns static
>   11.11.11.11 
>   11.11.11.22 wins 33.33.33.33 option66 tftp.server.org option150 44.44.44.4 option67 file.txt

In the worst case, it supports DHCP relay so you can relay DHCP requests from all VLAN to an external DHCP server

- Ubiquity Edge pro
  I'm not familiar with EdgeOs but it's based on Vyatta, which I used a lot, and it is possible without a doubt.

3 - To ensure that VLAN can not communicate together, you have to configure ACL (Cisco) or Firewall Rules (Ubiquity).

The SMB RV325 support 50 ACL rules, while the Ubiquity should not have limitation (other than memory) and you can either use interface based firewall or zone based firewall.

Comment: CPEs are normally configured with /24, but my plan is to reconfigure CPE LAN for /16, so three /24 subnetworks would be routed

Comment: Doing this would overlap network. I.E you will have 1 subnet on an interface and 3 networks that are subnets of the first one on other interfaces. This is not recommended, and a Cisco device will not allow it (Vyatta allow it so maybe EdgeOs allow it too, not sure). You need first to check if the CPE can NAT different networks, if yes no need to go to a weird config.

Comment: Ho also you need to check if you can add routes to the subnets on the CPE.

Answer (score 2):

> does this setup make sense?

I see no problem with the basic premise, as long as you meant 192.168.1.0/24 and not 192.168.1.0/16 for the "middle" network (unless you are planning to utilize proxy ARP - bad idea). Also assuming you are planning on performing NAT on the Cisco/EdgeRouter (or else you will need either dynamic routing such as OSPF or static routes on the CPE device).

A few suggestions, with the setup you describe you could configure a second EdgeRouter to provide redundancy (not sure if the Cisco platform is capable of this). With both devices connected to the CPE device, you would simply need to run VRRP on the internal LAN interfaces. This is more complex, but you can take a failure of one device without any of the offices being adversely affected.

If you don't go with a redundant setup (or if you have multiple WAN IP addresses from your provider) and if the CPE device can be configured to do so, then you could operate it in a bridge/bypass mode so the Cisco/EdgeRouer handles all the outside traffic directly. Eliminates a L3 network that isn't needed, avoids a double NAT situation on your side and gives you more control overall on your gateway device.

Finally, if you have the interface available, set up a fourth LAN network that you can plug into directly if needed, especially if you are not one of the three office tenants. That way you won't have to connect to one of the office networks (which they may object to) anytime you need to do maintenance.

> Do CISCO SMB RV325 or Ubiquiti EdgePro allow to configure separate DHCP pools per VLAN/PORT?

Yes, I believe they both do; although I have never used that particular Cisco product, that is a relatively basic feature for this level of device.

**Note:** the [Cisco RV325 is End of Sale](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/rv320-dual-gigabit-wan-vpn-router/eos-eol-notice-c51-738763.html) as I type this. You should instead be looking at the RV345 which is the replacement for the RV325.

> How do I ensure that VLANs/subnetworks are not reachable between them?

Specifics depend on chosen vendor/product, but the basic premise would be through the use of ACLs and/or firewall features. While there may also be means of simply not routing any traffic from one VLAN to another on the Cisco/EdgeRouter, depending on how the CPE device plays in the mix it may allow traffic to get "redirected" back into a different VLAN.

Comment: About the end of sales, [this notice](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/rv320-dual-gigabit-wan-vpn-router/eos-eol-notice-c51-738763.html) list only the  RV325-K9-AR I.E.  the Argentina model as E.O.S. Regarding VRRP, very good advice, but  for the CISCO both  the CLI reference guide and the use manual don't contain the word "vrrp" nor "hsrp" so it seems it's not supported. (see my answer for the links to the manuals)

Comment: @JFL, true, I didn't catch that it was only the Argentina model. However, this is still a likely indication it is on the tail end of it's life as a platform even for other models (along with the platform release date in 2013) and it would be better to look at the RV345.

Comment: I have find in the past that internet provider's CPEs would not route to LAN other than the LAN subnetwork. So CPEs LAN must be /16.

Comment: @M.E., then the only way this would work is if you are doing proxy ARP on the Cisco/EdgeRouter and proxy ARP is not a good solution. Rather you should look at setting the CPE device in bridge mode and allow your router to handle all the traffic.

Comment: Why is proxy ARP needed?

Comment: @M.E. you need proxy ARP because your CPE device will believe that IP addresses from 192.168.0.1-192.168.255.254 will be located on the local network (which includes your other /24 LAN networks). It will ARP for any traffic destined to those addresses instead of sending them along to the next L3 device. So your L3 device will have to respond to those ARP requests for the networks behind it with a proxy ARP so that the traffic is sent to it.

Comment: I understand. So what about just using L2, so no WAN ports are used, only LAN ports? so you will have basically three /24 subnets connected to one /16 subnet in the CPE. Is it possible to apply then sort kind of filtering/isolation between three networks? Is it possible to publish separate IP pools per VLAN/subnet?

Comment: @M.E. different subsets means you aren't just doing L2, you need L3. What you are describe now doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: The reason to do this trick is that a regular internet provider CPE won't have the routing capabilities to deal with subnets in their LAN side, so I was planning to do L2.

Comment: @M.E. understood, but there will still exist L3 boundaries and the CPE device will still think there are none. Everything else will understand and act on those boundaries. It just won't work.

Comment: After you mentioned proxy ARP I understood that, but what if you use the router/switch just as a L2 device? Then there won't be boundaries. My doubt is if it is still possible to assign either L3 firewalling per port or VLAN L2 firewall to isolate "subnets" (which we would better say sub network segments in this case). Also the other issue is to provide specific IP DHCP pools as per network segment.

Comment: @M.E. like I said, that won't work because you still have L3 boundaries.

Comment: I am trying to understand why there would be L3 boundaries  in this scenario. The CPE LAN would be 192.168.0.0/16, then there would be three /24 VLANs in the intermediate L2 device (192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24). Which means that for the CPE it is just a single LAN, but you can separate them in the L2. What is missing?

Comment: @M.E., you are missing the fundamental u derstanding of how networks work. Three VLaNs are three separate L2 domains and each has its own L3 subnet. It just doesn't work they way you are proposing.

Comment: A separate L2 domain does not have by definition its own L3 subnet. (separation of layers). L2 does not know anything about L3

Comment: @M.E., you are correct. But you also can't have a single L2 domain that encompasses three separate L2 domains (i.e. VLANs) and four L3 domains where one overlaps the other three L3 domains. It doesn't work that way. You are dragging out a pointless discussion about something that simply won't work as you are now describing; especially with a device in question that can't even be configured for dynamic/static routes.